# Cassandra -- Java hangs thread

Tags: java, cassandra, key-value-store

I am testing Cassandra. In the connection holder I have implemented a finalize method which is never called. This strategy has worked with other KV stores.

```
    public void finalize() throws Throwable {
    super.finalize();
    if (session != null) {
        session.close();
    }
    if (cluster != null) {
        cluster.close();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the program finishes it hangs indefinitely. However if in the main method I explicitly call ConnectionHolder.finalize(), the program finishes correctly. I have also tried a ShutdownHook which did not work.

Any idea of how to solve this?

cheers

Altober

Comment: Which CQL driver version are you using?

Comment: The last one 3.0.0-alpha4

Comment: Can you please provide an MCVE? I want to believe this is simply a thread pool that isn't shutdown. We'll know better if you provide a complete sample.